# If Statement error: Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new in Power BI and I'm more used to work with Excel. I try to translate following Excel formula:
*=IF(A2="UPL";0;IF(MID(D2;FIND("OTP";D2)+3;1)=" ";"1";(MID(D2;FIND("OTP";D2)+3;1))))*

in Power Bi as follows:
*Algo =
VAR FindIT = FIND("OTP",Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],1,0)
RETURN
IF(Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Type] = "UPL", 0,
IF(FindIT = BLANK(), 1, MID(Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],FindIT+3,1))
)*

Unfortunately I receive following error message:
Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.

My values are as follows:
[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cant mix Two datatypes in your output; In one part of if, you return an INT (literally 0/1), and is second you return a STRING

```
MID(Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],FindIT+3,1)
```

You must unify your output datatype -> everything to string or everything to INT

Comment: Thanks for your Help, both datatype are defined as Whole number, even if I create two separate columns this one doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

VAR FindIT = FIND("OTP",Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],1,0)
RETURN
    IF(FindIT > 0, CONVERT(MID(Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],FindIT+3,1),INTEGER), 0)

Comment: Propably you Select to many characters from MID (for example you get a dot)

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be returning BLANK in some cells therefore PowerBI isn't able to choose a data type for the column, wrap your code inside CONVERT(,INTEGER).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I followed your suggestion and I changed the code like this, but the error message is still the same:

Algo2 = 
VAR FindIT = CONVERT(FIND("OTP",Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],1,0),INTEGER)
RETURN
    IF(FindIT > 0, CONVERT(MID(Fixed_onTop_Data[Delivery Date],FindIT+3,1),INTEGER), 0)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Outcome is:
    (blank, or " ")
0
1
2